# tensor definition confusion as multilinear map

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products, tensor-products, tensors

I'm currently learning tensor as multilinear maps. $$T: \underset{p}{\underbrace{V^*\times \cdots \times V^*}}\times \underset{q}{\underbrace{V\times V \times \cdots  V\times V}} \rightarrow K\tag 1$$
I'm a little confused by $\times$ here. Does it mean cartesian product of vector spaces?

Comment: Yes, indeed it does.

Comment: @Gae.S. So from this definition, can I comprehend it as a linear map taking $(v^*, v^*....,v,v) \rightarrow k$? Taking a vector to a value?

Comment: No, it's not linear. It's multilinear. Meaning that its linear in each argument separately. Those are not the same.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos oh I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cross designates a Cartesian product, which is just a set-theoretic construction, but the result is just viewed as a Cartesian product, not as a vector space. There is in this context a lot of reason to talk about the individual components of the product, for instance it will be assumed that $T$ becomes a linear map when all components except one are fixed; this talks about $V^*$ or $V$ as a vector space, but not of the Cartesian product as a vector space. Indeed, one never needs to use scalar multiplication (which would multiply all components by that factor simultaneously) nor even of addition of elements of the product.