# Is there a corresepondence between abstract mixed tensors and mixed multilinear maps?

Tags: differential-geometry

I am reading Lee's book about smooth manifolds and I was wondering if there is a a correspondence between
[image]

and

[image]
I can only find the cases fot k=0 and l=0.

What am I missing. Many thannks in advance!

Comment: You can say the two spaces are equal by definition (which I’m sure is what Lee has in mind) or if you have a more abstract definition of tensor products of vector spaces, then you invoke *double duality* and the *universal property*, as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4163471/568204).

Comment: @peek-a-boo Yes, that mightbe the case that he meant that, but then again in "Smooth mfds" there are isomorphims that relate the "abstract" definition to the the more "concrete",i.e. mult.-linear maps. That confuses me. I had a look hat your explanation. It is very clear!Thanks. Is this to be found in any book? I had a look at Tu's books, as well as Jeffrey Lee's book. Somehow I couldn't find anything.

Comment: This is linear algebra so that’s where I’d look. I remember I learnt the abstract stuff from Steven Roman’s linear algebra book and also more generally in other algebra classes.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Now I am getting a bit confused about the tensor characterisation lemma. Is this something related or something different?

Comment: Different. That’s about tensor fields

Answer (score 1):

By the universal property of the tensor product, for every bilinear map $V \times W \to \mathbb{R}$ there is a unique linear map $V \otimes W \to \mathbb{R}$ or, in other words, an element of $(V \otimes W)^* = V^* \otimes W^*$.

This naturally extends to multiple tensor products and multilinear maps and together with the observation that $V^{**}=V$ gives you the correspondence.